# Add a custom note into add_order_note() function in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

By using add `add_order_note()` in Woocommerce can add custom notes. But in my case, once I got the value from javascript, and pass it into a PHP variable, the expected output is not I want.

See the code below:

```
<script>
        var x=document.getElementById('pickupStore').value;//x=my store

    </script>
    <?

    $store= "<script>document.write(x)</script>";
    echo $store;//it display "my store"
     $order = new WC_Order( $order_id ); 

     // The text for the note
    $note = __($store);

     // Add the note
     $order->add_order_note($note);

     // Save the data
     $order->save();
```

I run the code above and I check my order_notes section in Woocommerce admin page, it display `"document.write(x)"`, and not display "my store".
Is `add_order_note()` function cannot run the script?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This can't not work… You need to use Ajax, and it is the only way as php is executed before your javascript .

Comment: @LoicTheAztec i tried ajax, but wont work. Then i change to use cookie, it worked. Anyway, thank you for your reply.

Comment: Oh yes cookies is also a good alternative… You should publish an answer as it can be useful to the comunity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved.**
I used cookie to solve the problem. See my code below.

```
<script>
    var x = "my store";
    document.cookie = "Store = " + x;
</script>

<?php
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id ); 
    $note = __( $_COOKIE["Store"] );
    $order->add_order_note($note);
    $order->save();
?>
```